# How can I prevent saving record while its open on another computer?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my company we have a screen with fields of a **person**.

User **A** loads the person details - he **sees** the record.

Another user (**B**)  also loads this screen with the  **same record**.

user **B** can save **new information** for this record - and user **A won't** see the changes. ( because he opened the record before it was updated by user B).

we are talking about **asp.net** here.

What mechanism can I employ to **prevent user B** from saving  , until  user **A** close the window of the specific record.

I thought about adding a **datetime column**  to the sql server for each select  and to save the time when record was `selected...` and then compare datetimes - but is requires me to walk throught **all the sp's** and change  - and its `a lot of work`...

is there any more **smart** way of doing this ?

Comment: I think the truly difficult part is going to be finding a reliable way of _releasing_ the record.  The user can click a button to release it (and to close the browser window), but what if the user just closes the browser window manually?  What if the browser crashes?  What if the user just minimizes the window and walks away for the rest of the day?  What if the user leaves the browser window open because they need to refer to that data throughout the day?

Comment: I wish I could upvote your comment multiple times @David

Comment: I think that if you _must_ do something like this then make it into a warnings system rather than implimenting a draconian method. Tell your user that someone else has that record open and the date/time they opened it. Make it clear to them and still let them make changes.

Comment: We solve a similar problem by clearing the locks for a user when they log in. (Just started a session means they shouldn't have any open documents yet)  It's also tied to a timestamp of when the lock was created, anything over a day is not considered to still be locked.  Not the greatest solution, but one that works in practice for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a datetime column for last modification? If so, why not make the POST of changes first verify the row hasn't been modified since the GET. In the case it has been modified, show the changes and let the user reconcile them.

Another off the wall idea is to use something like `redis` (or even do it in a SQL table) and show who is editing the record currently via AJAX.

Comment: This is redis: http://redis.io/ There should be a version for Windows that is usable for production environments soon. In short, fast memory-based key-value store with other options. You could also use something like memcached or use in-process APS.NET caching to store this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options for you.

1) Add a usernameOpened column in your table and store the username of person A.  Then only allow that person to make changes...this can be problematic if you can't handle when they leave the record.

2) When the user loads the record keep a copy of it then compare the loaded record against the database on save.  If there are changes then it was changed after the form was loaded.

**Edit**: After re-reading the question I realize that I missed the requirement of waiting until Person A closes or releases the record.  My answer does not help with that.

Comment: The issue is, what if User A loads the row and then their computer crashes, or they go to lunch, or they leave for the day, then they get hit by a bus, get fired, or win the lottery? How can you confidently know when someone has abandoned a potential edit, and how do you "fix" that without some manual intervention?

Comment: Option number 2 fixes that.  When I hit the save button a check is done to make sure that I will not be overwriting any other changes.  I'm either shown the differences and asked to reconcile or prompted to overwrite the changes made by someone else.

Comment: I agree, and while I am not opposed to doing `a lot of work` to achieve a task that requires `a lot of work`, this seems to go against one of the OP's requirements. :-)

Comment: Sorry, just re-read the question....I missed the part about waiting until user A closes the window.

Answer (score 0):

When **Persona A** loads the details, create a lock of some sort.  When **A** closes it, remove the lock. Then  when saving, check to see if there are any open locks, if there are, do not allow the save/update to proceed.  Thus when **Person B** attempts to overwrite it while **A** has it open they are unable to.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which might also work for you is to let the `user B` save the record, and not put any locks at all.

You can then poll and notify `user A` or any other users which might have that record open to let them know that "This record has been updated". There are few options you can go with here, one of them is to show them a message box and Refresh button telling them to click OK to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

First, let user B know that user A has this record locked and they are in Read Only mode. Nobody wants to modify a lot of data only to discover when they hit Save that there are problems. There just shouldn't be any surprises.

Have a datetime field on the updated record: UpdateStartDateTime. While they are actively in the record and authenticed, this field should get udpated every 15 minutes. If they save or cancel, the field is cleared. Your app would have to periodically search for any of these records that are over the 15 min mark (Or whatever you think is appropriiate.). Unfortunately in a lot of client-server apps, users tend to stay in update forms way too long; I don't know about your situation.